# SQL Server - BCP - Format File - Issue with DateTime Values

Tags: t-sql, ssis, sql-server-2014, bcp

I am using SQL Server 2014.

I have a table with 2 columns defined as...

```
   EntryTime datetime(7) NULL
    ExitTime datetime(7) NULL
```

There is a file create via an SSIS package.
The date-time values in the data file are output in the form...

> 23-12-2019 06:54:57

In the format file (used by the BCP load) the fields are defined as...

```
  <COLUMN SOURCE = "5" NAME="EntryTime" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME2" SCALE="7"/>
    <COLUMN SOURCE = "6" NAME="ExitTime" xsi:type="SQLDATETIME2" SCALE="7" />
```

However the error I get while loading is...

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for
>   row 1, column 5 (EntryTime). Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The
>   OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error.
>   The provider did not give any information about the error. Msg 7330,
>   Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider
>   "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

what am I doing wrong with the data-types for these date/times columns?

Comment: `dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss` isn't an unambiguous format. If you're American, for example, they'll tell you there aren't 23 months in the year. Unless you have an unambigious format, there are only 2 regardless of data type and language (`yyyyMMdd` and `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.nnnnnn`), then i suggest inserting the data into a `varchar` in a staging table, and then using `CONVERT` and a style code to get the correct value.

Comment: I am in the UK so the date/time values in the file are...dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: But that doesn't mean that the language of the login you are using is `BRITISH`. Unambiguous dates are *always* the way to go.

Comment: I wonder if I can specify a collation in the format file of BRITISH so the  BCP load process see the datetimes as dd-mm-yyyy hh:mm:ss

Comment: You can specify the collation of columns in format files, yes (you can see this in the documentations [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/create-a-format-file-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#examples)), but date formats have nothing to do with collations.

Comment: The other option I have is to format the date-time value in the SSIS package before uploading to the database...

Comment: If you can control the format of the date in the text file, that would make it ideal too. considering you have a date and time, then something like `'2019-12-23T06:54:57` would be appropriate.

Comment: Thanks Larnu, I give this a go.

Comment: I just noticed, you declare your column as a `datetime(7)`; that makes no sense. `datetime` takes no precision option; it's accurate to 1/300th of a second whether you "like it or not". I assume you mean `datetime2`. If so, and you never have an nano seconds, then save the space and use a `datetime2(0)`.

Comment: @Larnu - agreed the datetime2 data-type is a waste of space and not needed. I have changed to datetime and used a datetime format of yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and this worked.